Maintaining SVN-style Header Comments in Git Using Filters or Hooks
I’m working on a Git-based project with DevOps where I need to maintain SVN-style header comments for selected .txt files. Specifically, I want to include headers with placeholders like $Id$, $Author$, $Date$, and $Revision$, which should be automatically updated.
I have two text files, test.txt and test1.txt, with the following contents:
test.txt:
"This is a test file with ID_PLACEHOLDER, DATE_PLACEHOLDER, and AUTHOR_PLACEHOLDER."
File: $Id: test.txt | Fri Aug 9 09:25:32 2024 +0530 | Rakshith K  $
Author: $Author: Rakshith K <rakshith.k@bixbytessolutions.com> $
Date: $Date:   Fri Aug 9 09:25:32 2024 +0530 $
Revision: $Revision: 067f63af61395ce440d776a77cf065fa0f223f97 $

test1.txt:
"This is a test1 file with ID_PLACEHOLDER, DATE_PLACEHOLDER, and AUTHOR_PLACEHOLDER."
File: $Id: test1.txt | Fri Aug 9 09:25:32 2024 +0530 | Rakshith K  $
Author: $Author: Rakshith K <rakshith.k@bixbytessolutions.com> $
Date: $Date:   Fri Aug 10 09:25:32 2024 +0530 $
Revision: $Revision: 067f63af61395ce440d776a77cf065fa0f223uyj $

Issue:

When I clone the repository to a new location, the header comments are correctly updated.
However, if I pull changes in the same repository or a different location, the header comments are not updated, although the latest changes to the files are applied.

Current Setup:

My global .gitconfig includes:
[user]
    name = Rakshith K
    email = rakshith.k@bixbytessolutions.com
[filter "rcs-keywords"]
    clean = .git_filters/rcs-keywords.clean
    smudge = .git_filters/rcs-keywords.smudge


The rcs-keywords.clean file:
#!/usr/bin/perl -p
s/\$Id[^\$]*\$/\$Id\$/;
s/\$Date[^\$]*\$/\$Date\$/;
s/\$Author[^\$]*\$/\$Author\$/;
s/\$Source[^\$]*\$/\$Source\$/;
s/\$File[^\$]*\$/\$File\$/;
s/\$Revision[^\$]*\$/\$Revision\$/;


The rcs-keywords.smudge file:
#!/usr/bin/perl
$path = shift;
$path =~ /.*\/(.*)/;
$filename = $1;

if (0 == length($filename)) {
    $filename = $path;
}

$rev = `git log -- $path | head -n 3`;
$rev =~ /^Author:\s*(.*)\s*$/m;
$author = $1;
$author =~ /\s*(.*)\s*<.*/;
$name = $1;
$rev =~ /^Date:\s*(.*)\s*$/m;
$date = $1;
$rev =~ /^commit (.*)$/m;
$ident = $1;

while (<STDIN>) {
    s/\$Date[^\$]*\$/\$Date:   $date \$/;
    s/\$Author[^\$]*\$/\$Author: $author \$/;
    s/\$Id[^\$]*\$/\$Id: $filename | $date | $name \$/;
    s/\$File[^\$]*\$/\$File:   $filename \$/;
    s/\$Source[^\$]*\$/\$Source: $path \$/;
    s/\$Revision[^\$]*\$/\$Revision: $ident \$/;
} continue {
    print or die "-p destination: $!\n";
}



Question:
The goal is to have the $Id$, $Author$, $Date$, and $Revision$ placeholders automatically updated both while pull and clone.
I am considering switching to using Git hooks instead of filters. Should I remove the rcs-keywords.smudge and rcs-keywords.clean files if I implement Git hooks? Or can I achieve the desired functionality with these existing filter files along with Git hooks?
Any suggestions or solutions to address the issue of header comments not updating correctly during pulls would be greatly appreciated.

Define "updating correctly". Say, a file has been checked out to the worktree and now has the correct headers (for some definition of "correct"). Then you pull, but the file is not changed by the new commit. Here, the file will not be checked out again and its old content including old RCS headers will remain in the file. This mode of operation is fundamental in Git. There's no way around it except to taint all checked-out files manually in order to force Git to overwrite them.

The problem seems to be the git log invocation. It assumes that HEAD has already been updated by the time the smudge filter runs. But this may not be the case.

There are security implications in place... if you modify files as they are committed (so that you can update date author, etc), there is no way to maike it into the commit you just finished.

Can you please explain more thoroughly?
